# While automating the [Freecharge](https://www.freecharge.in/) Website, I am not able to click on Login with Selenium tool using Java

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate Freecharge Website in Selenium using Java. As I am trying to click on Login tab,  Login page is not displaying(nothing is happening from the click on Login tab). I used the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.freecharge.in/");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Login/Register")));
    //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login/Register")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-reactid = '.pegzwc3vuo.0.0.1.0.0']")).click();
}
```

Comment: Try using ` Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.ClassName("_3mvx0")).Click();` i tried and it worked.

Comment: For me it is showing _driverInstance can not be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Try waiting until the page is completely loaded. Because I clicked on the button and it opened a popup. At which line you got the error? @Pulkit Agarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code. Just now i have executed the application with the xpath.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_13Tms']/a")).click();

Answer (score 0):

use `driver.get("https://www.freecharge.in")` instead of navigate().to

update:

1) load main page

`driver.get("https://www.freecharge.in");`

2) naviate to merchant area which contains the Login Area

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='itrbU _14dL7']")).click();`

3) seach for Text LOGIN and click it
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'LOGIN')]")).click();`

Comment: I am able to login to Freecharge("https://www.freecharge.in") with driver.navigate().to. The real issue is not able to click on Login Tab

Comment: which Login Tab? I don't see any Login button/tab [here](http://i64.tinypic.com/346pzd5.png) using the provided address - if you change the address to https://merchant.freecharge.in/#/ there is a Login..